# Custom NewForm & EditForm for Lists in app web of SharePoint-hosted apps

Tags: list, app, visual-studio-2013, web, newform

My goal is to create a custom NewForm and EditForm for an existing SharePoint list in the app web of a sharepoint-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 online using Visual Studio 2013. In addition to a custom layout, the forms should also use custom JavaScript.

I have read and worked through several tutorials like

[SharePoint 2010 Cookbook: How to Create a Custom List Edit Form for Development in Visual Studio 2010](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/12/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-a-customized-list-edit-form-for-development-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

This tutorial requires to open the list in SharePoint Designer.

My question now: How can I open and edit lists of the app web in SharePoint Designer (I am working with SharePoint Designer 2013)? Is it even possible? Or is there another possibility to create a custom NewForm and EditForm for a list in the app web of a sharepoint-hosted app for SharePoint 2013 online using Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the new form and edit form pages using SharePoint Designer in SP hosted apps. Better idea would be to go for custom pages and link them to your list using CSOM scripts.

Have a look at these links for more details - [here](http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-apps-cusom-list-forms) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c30d9778-cc80-42ca-a3fd-82a9f37f6b36/custom-list-forms-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps)